# Watch folder and rename file extension

Tags: rename, watch

Good day, I'm trying to find a way to watch a folder, and as soon as it see's an xml file/s, it will change it's extension to .txt

I am trying to do this in powershell, hope this question find you all well.

Comment: To give a little bit more information, basically what I wanted to do is 1. watch the folder for xml files. 2. when xml file copied to this folder, I want to do some conversion and execute command line $doc = Get-Content C:\xml\filename.xml then $doc1.job.sample then out-file to same filename but txt extension. Please let me know if this makes sense, thanks

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).